# How could i use another weighting model in whoosh?

Tags: nlp, information-retrieval, whoosh

If i want to use the Language Model as the weighting model,how could i do.The default function is BM-25 model,And i have not find the Language model in scoring class,It really confused me.

Answer (score 0):

Because we can't find Whoosh original author Matt Chaput,
some guys try to restart the whoosh project on Github.

Language model in weighting class is a good idea for future development,
Current we are working on fix major bugs but later will work on new features.

I'm new to the source code but currently reading the scoring code.
As my opinion, with current whoosh code you have two options:

use whoosh.scoring.FunctionWeighting, provide a customized weighting function.
Implement a new WeightingModel, inherit from whoosh.scoring.FunctionWeighting class.
You could read scoring.py and get some examples.